# store data in a panel

Tags: extjs, panel, store

I create a panel that must show the data of a store but it shows nothing.
This is my panel:

```
pnl = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        id          : 'profile',
        renderTo    : 'itemselector',
        items:[{
                xtype       : 'itemselector',
                name        : 'itemselector',
                fieldLabel  : 'Gestion des groupes:',
                imagePath   : 'ext/examples/multiselect/images/',
                multiselects: [{
                        width   : 275,
                        height  : 220,
                        store   : store1,
                        displayField: 'text'
                },{
                        width   : 275,
                        height  : 220,
                        store   : [['10','Ten']]
                }]
        }],
    });
```

and this is my store:

```
store1 = new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
         id         : 'StoreGroupe'
        ,url        : 'st1.php'
        ,reader     : new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                        root            : 'data',
                        totalProperty   : 'rows',
                        id              : 'ReaderGroupes',
                        fields          : [{name:'Gname'}]
                    })
});
```

It works only when I use a static store like this:

```
 store1 = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    data    :  [['1', 'One'], ['2', 'Two'], ['3', 'Three'], ['4', 'Four'], ['5', 'Five'],['6', 'Six']],
    fields  :  ['value','text']
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The FormPanel is configured to display the "text" field as a multiselect. However, the JsonReader in the GroupingStore does not include a "text" field. The ArrayStore works because a "text" field is defined for the store.

Define a "text" field for the JsonReader and make sure that the server returns a "text" field and it should work.

Comment: so how can I define "text" field in the JsonReader.

Comment: @Fares Omrani Try:`fields : [{name:'text'}]` instead of the current fields. Also, the server needs to return JSON with a "text" field.  Or, if the JSON contains a field by another name that should be mapped to "text" in the JsonStore, try `fields : [{name:'text', mapping:'jsonFieldName'}]`.

Comment: I used this store but still don't show anything:

    store1 = new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
             id         : 'StoreGroupe'
            ,url        : 'st1.php'
            ,reader     : new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                            root            : 'data',
                            totalProperty   : 'rows',
                            id              : 'ReaderGroupes',
          fields    : [{name:'text', mapping:'Gname'}]
                        })
    });

Comment: @Far It sounds like there could be an issue matching what the JsonReader expects with the JSON data from the server. For instance, does the JSON contain a root field named "data" that holds the "Gname" fields? If not, remove the `root : 'data'` property.

Comment: This is what the Json contains: {success: true, rows:1, data:[{"G_ID":"1","Gname":"defaut"}]}

Comment: @Far That looks like it should work. I'll try a few things and let you know if I find a solution.